# Adding text to bitmap before saving

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, paint, drawtext

I am taking a drawable converting it to a muteable bitmap, creating a canvas and painting text on it, adding the canvas to the image and then saving the bitmap to a file.  It is saving the image correctly but the text is not on the image that is saved. I have looked at other answers and tried them but nothing seems to be working.

This is the code:

```
  public void createTitleImageFromDrawable(){

    // Create file object for saving the the bitmap
    File file = new File(MainActivity.mRootDirectoryForFrontViewImages + "front_view_image_day00001.PNG");
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Create a bitmap from the title image drawable
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dory);

    // Create a mutable version of the bitmap to draw on it
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = bm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);//&lt;--true makes copy mutable

    // Create a new canvas and set it to the new muteable bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

    // Create paint object and set up settings for it
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Text Color
    paint.setTextSize(40); // Text Size


    // Using the canvas draw on the muteable bitmap
     canvas.drawText("Test", 10, 10, paint);

    // Put the muteable file into the file
    mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);

    try {
        outStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A few notes: 1) Use the `setTextSize()` method, not `setStrokeWidth()`. 2) A size of 12, which coincidentally is the default text size, is pretty small; you're probably just not seeing the text. 3) The `drawBitmap()` call is just drawing the Bitmap onto itself, and is pointless. 4) The coordinates passed into `drawText()` are for the left point of the text's baseline, not its top.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got rid of stroke width and set text to 40, removed the canvas drawBitmap and removed setXfermode but still the same unfortunately. Edited my question with those changes.

Comment: Well, depending on the size of the image and how you're viewing it, 40 can still be relatively small. And if you haven't changed the coordinates in the `drawText()` method, most of the text is extending beyond the top of the image in the upper-left corner.

Comment: Great you are right. Thanks! I played with the size and the position and now I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here,I am putting code which will help you much.please understand this code and apply changes as per your requirement.you can put your text exact position of image where you did touch.

```
public void setCBitmap(Bitmap bitmap2, MotionEvent e, String name) {
    float eventX = e.getX();
    float eventY = e.getY();
    float[] eventXY = new float[] { eventX, eventY };

    Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
    ((ImageView) main_iMG).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

    invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
    int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
    int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);
    Canvas canvas = null;
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap2);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(45);


    Paint mpaint= new Paint();
    mpaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f9bf3a"));
    mpaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    float w = paint.measureText(name)/2;
    float textSize = paint.getTextSize();
    Paint paint1= new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);



    Paint p= new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF( x-13, y -(textSize+3), x + paint.measureText(name)+13,y+23), 7, 7, p);


    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF( x-10, y -(textSize), x + paint.measureText(name)+10,y+20),  7,7,mpaint);
    canvas.drawText(name, x, y, paint);

    main_iMG.setImageBitmap(bitmap2)}
```

Comment: I don't see from this what the problem is